# how to integration test nodeJS mongo

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose

As part of setting up our continuous integration cycle we are defining standard templates for unit and integration test for our mean applications.
One basic test is to verify some settings in a mongo collection (name Setting)
We are using Mocha, Should, Require and super test

I've defined the following test

> var request = require('supertest');
>   describe('configuration',function(){
>
> ```
> before(function(done) {
>     // In our tests we use the test db
>     mongoose.connect(config.db);
>     done();
> });
> describe('required configuration ',function(){
>      it('should return Settings Object',function(done){
>         mongoose.Setting.findOne({key:'ABC'}, function(foundSetting){
>             foundSetting.value.should.equal('XYZ');
>             done();
>         });
>     })
>
> });
> ```
>
> })

which always errors with 'TypeError: Cannot call method 'findOne' of undefined'

can anyone point me in the right direction how to use integration test on mongo objects (also e.g. checking a collection count

Answer (score 0):

Considering Setting is a mongoose model you would have this at the end of the model file

```
setting.js

...
module.exports = mongoose.model('Setting', settingSchema)
```

And I think if you require this model in your test file like this

```
test.js

var Setting = require('./setting')
```

Then you could call `Setting.findOne` instead of `mongoose.Setting.findOne` inside the actual test case and it should work fine. Also you should make sure you have successfully connected to your test database before you do this. It is a good practice to clean the tested collection in a before hook

```
before(function(done) {
    // Connect to database here

    Setting.remove({}, function(err) {
        if (err)
            throw err
        else
            done()
    })
})
```

and do the same thing `afterEach` test case.

I don't see where and how you use supertest in your snippet but I believe it is the right tool. Again, in your before hook you could first call `request = request(require('./app'))` where app.js exports your express application. Moreover, you could move the code that connects to the database to your app.js, which feels more environment-independent.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing unit and integration test, you should install required libraries

1. Install mocha framework globally

   ```
   sudo npm install -g mocha
   ```
2. Install chai assertion library and HTTP plug-in

   ```
   npm install chai
   npm install chai-http
   ```
3. Add mocha command to your package.json file

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "test": "mocha",
     "start": "nodemon app.js"
    }
   ```

Usage of mocha framework and chai assertion library can be seen in code below

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe("Integration Test Case 1",() => {
it("Sign Up-In", () => {

    // Sign Up
    chai.request("localhost:5000/api/users")
        .post("/signup")
        .send(createdUser)
        .end(async (error, response) => {
            await response.should.have.status(201);

            // Sign In
            chai.request("localhost:5000/api/users")
                .get("/signin")
                .send(userCredential)
                .end(async (error, response) => {
                    await response.should.have.status(202);
}};
```